# How to paginate based on with relation data laravel

Tags: mysql, eloquent, pagination, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have come across a query.

```
$users = User::whereHas('role', function ($q) {
                $q->where('role_id', 3);
         })
        ->with(['property_managements.new_notifications.type'])
        ->with(['property_managements' => function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('new_notifications');
        }])
        ->whereHas('property_managements.new_notifications');
$data['users'] = $users->get();

I need to get paginate the data based on new_notifications in the relation and also order the data based on notification_date column in the relation.
```

I have tried changing the code like,

```
    ->with(['property_managements' => function ($q) {
        $q->whereHas('new_notifications')
          ->orderBy('notification_date','asc')
          ->paginate(10);
    }])
```

But the result was not order by notification date and also it is not paginated